# Construct Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a program that parses the filesystem of a server (which is hosting multiple domains) for the installed web-frameworks, installed plugins, version, themes... So on a server can be a domain, in which is a Wordpress and two TYPO3 installations.
I am trying to construct one big JSON file where all the information is being stored. My idea was to iteratively build smaller dictionaries that have information which belongs together, then -- when I have them all together -- join them to one big dict and write that out as JSON.
Here is a small excerpt to visualize

```
www.this.is.a.domain: {
frameworks:
    {
        wordpress: {
            path: [{
                path/to/my/first/wp: {
                    plugins: [
                        {
                            name: foo,
                            status: active
                        },
                        {
                            name: bar,
                            status: inactive
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }]
        },
        typo3: {
            path: [{
                path/to/my/first/typo3: {
                    version: 1.2.3,
                    plugins: [
                        {
                            name: foo,
                            status: active
                        },
                        {
                            name: bar,
                            status: inactive
                        }
                    ]
                },
                path/to/my/second/typo3: {
                    version: 3.4.5,
                    plugins: [
                        {
                            name: foo,
                            status: inactive
                        },
                        {
                            name: baz,
                            status: active
                        }
                    ]
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now for my problem:
Look at the TYPO3 section. I have two different installations in different paths. In a Python dictionary I would have a list of dictionaries like `{path: [{path01: {plugins:[{...}]}, {path02: {plugins:[{...}]}]}`.
The problem that I have is if I have another dict with the theme of my TYPO3 like `{path: [{path/to/my/first/typo3: {theme: baz}}]}` how can I insert that information in my first dict as I don't know at which position of my list the correct path is. Having lists in the dictionary complicates things extremely but I need them because I don't have all the information at the same time. First I parse the first installation path, collect all info I can get, and then off to the next path. So I need to append to a list but I can't put additional information into a dict that is in a list when my key for where I want to put my additional information is like the path which is inside of a dict in a list.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a better suited data structure to build my JSON?

**Simply put:** How do I add additional information to a dictionary that sits in a list inside a dictionary (like the theme example) when the thing I can search for in the big dictionary is a deeply nested key inside a list?

**Minimal example:**
How do I add

```
{plugins: [
    {
        name: foo,
        status: active
    },
    {
        name: bar,
        status: inactive
    }
]}
```

to

```
dict = {'domain': {'vt': {'path': [{'p1': {'version': '1.2.3'}}, {'p2': {'version': '2.2.3'}}]}}}
```

as an additional value for `'p2'`?

Comment: JSON *does* need explicit lists. JSON objects and arrays map directly to Python dicts and lists, and vice versa.

Comment: Not sure what the question really is, but seems you don't want to have a list for plugins?... Why not just make plugins a dict, keyed off of name?

Comment: The structure you showed looks like what you want. I'm not clear on why that's not working for you.

Comment: sure. but in JSON lists are marked by curly braces. there are no additional square brackets. but I know that additional brackets doesn't make the JSON incorrect.

Comment: No, in JSON lists are marked by square braces. _Objects_ (equivalent to python dicts) are marked by curly braces.

Comment: @glibdud: The structure that I printed is not what I have. I have a list of paths in my dictionary. If I later want to add something to that path (like the theme), I don't know how.

Comment: If all you're using in your data structure is lists, dicts, numbers, and strings, all those things map perfectly to JSON equivalents. Build your structure however it makes sense in python and don't worry about how it will look in JSON.

Comment: That is what I'm doing. Therefore I have lists in my dict. But if I later want to add something to a dict in a list, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Ok, you might want to edit your question and remove the references to JSON, because that's not relevant but that's what people are going to focus on.

Comment: Right. Did that. I hope my question is clearer now.